# php querying for data just inserted...by itself

Tags: php

I don't know how to title this...but anyway,

In my script if data doesn't exist, i insert a new row into a database and then check again for that row, for example:

```
1 search the db

2 if nothing
    include(create.php) -> create entry

3 search the db for that row
```

Am I going to have to put in a `usleep(1000000);` between the `include` and the next search on the db? or is there something I am missing?

THanks!

Comment: What is your code for search of data?

Comment: mysql query, then check number of rows

Comment: if you just want to to check if the `insert` is successful, use `mysql_affected_rows($link)` or `mysqli_affected_rows($link)`

Comment: Also look into getting the last inserted id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the file create.php on top of your php script and call the functions you required inside this block

```
if ($number_of_rows < 1) { //call the functions from create.php you need here}
```

Comment: If i think i understand you, in my code the calls to db are outside of the include. all the include does it insert the data.

Comment: call the insert outside the include,it should work.Remove the include, copy paste the code of creat.php file into the bracket, see if it works.Then i will explain to you why.Please try

Comment: you mean save the insert as a variable in the page im including... then back on the main page perform the insert using that variable?

Comment: `include` can be called anywhere in the script. Except for the `scope` of the included code there won't be any change. `variables` will inherit scope, while `classes` and `functions` will have global scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that

```
$query="Select * from table where id='23'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
//result find in sql table
}else{

$query1="INSERT INTO table (schema) values(values)";
$result=mysql_query($query1);
}

sleep(1);


$query="select *...."
```

You can also use mysql `INTERVAL` query.It will automatic make a query after a particular interval and search for data.

Comment: that's what i think i'll have to do...I wanted to see if there is another way

Comment: @iight I think there is no another way or not any shortcut.This is the basic way

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, why even have a `create.php` used in that manner anyway? Include `create.php` at the top of the page, put all the insert syntax into a function, and call it later on in your main script. That would work.

Or even better, don't even bother including it. Just run the queries straight in your main page. That way if you need to change something, you won't have to affect other pages.

Comment: good points, but the included page is used elsewhere. I'm going to just turn this all to a function i guess